# No me salta el error cuando introduzco un error negativo

Tags: c++

```
if ((_base||_altura) <= 0){
   throw string {"ERROR: la base y la altura tienen que ser mayor que 0 "};
}
else {
   base = _base;
   altura = _altura;
}
```

Este es el codigo que tengo hecho y cuando pongo un valor negativo no me salta error pero si cuando pongo 0

Answer (score 5):

El problema está en cómo estás poniendo los paréntesis en el `if`:

```
if ((_base||_altura) <= 0){
```

Tal y como está ahora mismo, estás procesando primero `(_base||_altura)` y el resultado lo estás comparando con `<= 0`. Entonces el problema es que si cualquiera de los dos números es distinto de cero, el OR devolverá 1 que es un valor mayor o igual que cero y se entrará en el `if`.

La solución sería comparar cada uno de los valores con cero individualmente:

```
if (_base <= 0 || _altura <= 0){
   throw string {"ERROR: la base y la altura tienen que ser mayor que 0 "};
}
else {
   base = _base;
   altura = _altura;
}
```